# Trouble in Python and SQL Server Connector

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server using the Python code:

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=digitest-02;DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=test@#^%$')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM wellsfargo.dbo.predictions')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

But getting error instead of a connection output:

```
C:\Users\BhaskarDas\PycharmProjects\SQLConnector_RW\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/BhaskarDas/PycharmProjects/SQLConnector_RW/SQLReadWrite.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/BhaskarDas/PycharmProjects/SQLConnector_RW/SQLReadWrite.py", line 3, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=digitest-02;DATABASE=test;UID=sa;PWD=test@#^%$')
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working when I have given Server IP Address instead of the Server Name.